# VS2010 - Change public class names only when build solution in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class, plugins, obfuscation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free obfuscation tools for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805549/free-obfuscation-tools-for-net)

I have my C# application and:
When I'm opening my software in "Just Decompiler" or any decompiler - I can see the names of the forms/classes ... and any public class/object I created. By the way I used an obfuscator.

For a long time I'm looking for a software/plugin that will change all of my class's names (includes the public classes - because no 3rd party app will use it).

I'm looking for a plugin that will only change all that public forms/classes names for example:
I have a form that called "MyAlgos" and I want it to just rename it -> only when I build the solution - so when I'm programming i'll see the name "MyAlgos" but after I'll open my builded software assembly in a decompiler - I'll see it something like Dhd436bxSg... :)

Hope something similar is out there for my needs.
Thanks!

[screen shot http://s1.postimage.org/4jgxaubu7/image46.png](http://s1.postimage.org/4jgxaubu7/image46.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If buying a decent obfuscator is not an option make as much of your code "private", "protected" and "internal", then make empty public wrappers for the rest. Not only classes but also methods and properties.
The obfuscator leaves them visible because "public" means they may be in use by other assemblies and they need to be able to find what they'd need

Comment: Is there a way to make a form to "privare" / "protected"? last time VS2010 won't let me...

Comment: You can make it "internal" - anything that's not public the obfuscator is free to hide. And having a form isn't a fact that's a secret - users can see it anyway. What's a secret is how it works. You can definitely make its important methods private, protected or internal

Comment: Tried a second ago to make a public form (WPF)
from: 
public partial class NameOfForm : Window
to:
internal partial class NameOfForm : Window

and get this error when trying to build:
Partial declarations of 'NameOfForm' have conflicting accessibility modifiers

Comment: WPF is more difficult because the BAML it stores in assemblies can also be decompiled. Also deserializing it may need access to some public dependency properties for binding. I'd assumed WinForms. For WPF you definitely need a higher end obfuscator - you could manually make your code obfuscate-able but it will cost you more than buying one.

Answer (score 1):

[Crypto Obfuscator for .NET](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) does that, however it's not free. There are some free obfuscation tools listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805549/free-obfuscation-tools-for-net).

Comment: what about ".NET Reactor" ?

Comment: I have never tried that software, but usually any .NET obfuscator offers types and members renaming. You might want to make sure of that in case you want to purchase one, however.

Comment: OK thanks... but why is an obfuscator will change the public class? i don't think that this is possible because: (quote of "Sten Petrov"): "public" means they may be in use by other assemblies and they need to be able to find what they'd need

Comment: A decent obfuscator doesn't simply rename classes, it refactors references to them so that no usages are broken.

Comment: @user1651338: my statement referred to keeping the signatures of methods and classes visible. A good obfuscator (and there are some out there) can alter the body of these methods and make the actual logic unreadable. Focus on obscuring what really matters in your app if not everything can be obscured